# ““Meteor - tsega/meteor-bootstrap3-datetimepicker TypeError: locale() locale it is not loaded from moment locales!“

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

The console log retun this error

```
tsega/meteor-bootstrap3-datetimepicker TypeError: locale() locale it is
not loaded from moment locales!
```

I'm using meteor with this version Meteor 1.4.1.1 with the [tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker](https://atmospherejs.com/tsega/bootstrap3-datetimepicker) v4.17.37_1 and [momentjs:moment](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment) v2.14.4 packages.

As per the example I have the following code to initialize the date time picker:

```
Template.nuovoCantiere.onRendered( () => {
  $( '.datetimepicker' ).datetimepicker({
    timeZone: 'Europe/Rome',
    format: 'D/MM/YYYY',
    locale: 'it'
  });
});
```

I read that the moment.js packages has been flagged as not working:

> "Flagged Package
>   This package has been flagged as not working by the community. Use at your own risk."

So I tried to use the NPM version of moment.js:

```
var moment = require('moment');
require('moment/locale/it');

Template.nuovoCantiere.onRendered( () => {
  $( '.datetimepicker' ).datetimepicker({
      timeZone: 'Europe/Rome',
      format: 'D/MM/YYYY',
      locale: 'it'
  });
});
```

but the console returns the same error

`TypeError: locale() locale it is not loaded from moment locales!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've passed by the very same situation. And it has honestly a very simple solution concerning Meteor development:

1. $ meteor add [rzymek:moment](https://atmospherejs.com/rzymek/moment)
2. $ meteor add [rzymek:moment-locale-it](https://atmospherejs.com/rzymek/moment-locale-it)

Restart your app and that's it. There's no need to reference a node-module (i.e var moment = require('moment');) and stuff.